# Angular md-switch: align bar and thumb when width increased

Tags: angular

When increasing the width of an md-switch, how do you right-align the thumb and bar when the switch is checked?

Example of problem:

Unchecked:

[image: Unchecked]

Checked:

[image: Checked]

I've tried numerous things including setting container sizes but so far nothing. Setting the md-container and thumb-container to the same size just results in the thumb sliding past the end of the bar:

[image]

Surely there should be a single "global"-md setting which allows scaling of the bar and thumb in tandem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok you need to update material classes :

```
md-switch .md-bar{
   width:70px;
}

md-switch.md-checked .md-thumb{
  left:40px;
}
```

This example is ok for a width equals to 70px. But you could change it with your own width.

Comment: This has the same problem as setting the container widths: the appropriate left value is some fraction of the switch width which I guess can only be found by trial and error? Ideally, I would like to set a single value which would scale the bar and thumb appropriatly.

Comment: Are you testing that?